# How to find first letter of each value in array using charAt in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

As the title depicts, i'm trying to find the first letter of each value in a string array in Java using charAt. Once I used the included code, I got an error saying that they are incompatible type, where char cannot be converted to String. Any help? Thanks.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
{
    firstName [i] = name[i].charAt(0);           
}
```

Comment: You haven't posted any code.

Comment: What are `firstName` and `name`? The error message seems rather clear.

Comment: What is arraySize, firstName and name? what types are they?

Comment: @shree.pat18  already defined. im trying to set values of the array firstName to be the first letter of each value of array name.

Comment: That will only work if `firstName` is a `char[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `char` to a `String` using [`Character.toString(char)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString%28char%29), like

```
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    firstName[i] = Character.toString(name[i].charAt(0));           
}
```

or change `firstName` to a `char[]` like

```
char[] firstName = new char[arraySize];
for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
    firstName[i] = name[i].charAt(0);           
}
```

A one character `char` is a primitive type, a `String` is an `Object` type (a `char` is not a `String`). Also, please change the variable name because a letter is not a name. Perhaps `firstInitial`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a String from the entry in the name array not a char.

Use this instead

```
firstName [i] = name[i].substring(0, 1);
```